# The function $G: x \mapsto 2^{x^2}$ maps $\mathbb{R}$ onto $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : x \geq 1 \}$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

> Let $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $Y = \{x \in \mathbb{R} :x ≥ 1\}$, and define $G : X → Y$ by $$G(x) = e^{x^2}.$$
> Prove that $G$ is onto.

Is this going along the right path and if so how do get the function to equal $y$?

> $G: \mathbb{R} \to\mathbb{N}_1$. Let $y$$\in $$\mathbb{N_1}$.
>
> *claim:* $\sqrt{\ln y}$ maps to $y$.
>
> Does $\sqrt{\ln y}$ belong to $\mathbb{N_1}$? Yes because $y \in \mathbb{N_1}$, $G( \sqrt{\ln y})=e^{(\sqrt{\ln y})^2}$.

Comment: What does $e_2$ denote?

Comment: Do you mean $G(x) = e^{x^2}$, perhaps?

Comment: What is $e_{2}^{x}$?

Comment: @ChasBrown: Indeed. :)

Comment: yes my error it should be $x^2$

Comment: Why is this labelled as discrete mathematics?

Comment: Why is the codomain given as $\mathbb{N}_1$? $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer being that it is the same as $Y = \{x ∈ R|x ≥ 1\}$

Comment: Please take a look at the [MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting help.

Comment: @extremeaxe5 Because it is covered in discrete mathematics under Functions, Sequences and Relations.

Comment: all i know is that i have to use logs but don't know how to start.

Comment: Is $R$ the ring of integers? $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer $\mathbb{R} $= ${x | -∞ < x <∞}$ in other words the set real numbers

Comment: $\frac32 \: \in \: \{x\in R \: | \: x\geq 1\} \;\;\;$ but $\;\;\; \frac32 \not\in \mathbb{N}_1 \;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Answer (score 4):

For any y $\in$ Y we have to show that there exists an x in X such that G(x) = y.

Now,
$$G(x)=y$$
$$\implies e^{x^2} = y$$
$$\implies x^2 = \ln y $$
$$\implies x = \pm \sqrt {\ln y}$$

Since, y $\in$ Y, y $\ge 1$ and hence $\ln y\ge 0$ and $\pm \sqrt {\ln y}$ is well defined and is in X.Thus for any real y in Y there are two reals x in X, such that G(x) = y. Thus, $G:X \rightarrow Y$ is onto.

Answer (score 1):

Pick an arbitrary element from within the range of the function, and show that the preimage of the element is non-empty.

Answer (score 1):

For any $y\in Y$, there is $x= \sqrt{\ln y} \in X$ such that $G(x)=y$.

Comment: If i may ask how did you know to apply $\sqrt{\ln y}$ to the general definition of a surjective function to assist with solving the problem at hand.

Comment: @ITken,  By definition, the function is surjective iff every $y\in Y$ has an $x\in X$ such that $y=e^{x^2}$.  So we invert it and ask, is $x=\pm\sqrt[2]{\ln y}$ real valued for all $y\in[0,\infty)$?

Comment: @ITken let $e^{x^2}=y$. Then solve $x$ from the equation.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $g(x)=e^{x^2}$ is symmetric about the y-axis. Also $g$ is continuous and strictly increasing in $\mathbb{R}^+$ with $g(0)=1$

Comment: You can aways use the preimage concept as suggested by jchun too. :)

Answer (score 0):

A function is surjective (onto) iff every element in the codomain is mapped to by at least one element in the domain.

So to determine if: $\forall y\in [1, \infty), \exists x\in \mathbb R: y=e^{x^2}$, we ask, do the roots $x=\pm \sqrt[2]{\ln y}$ have a real value for all $y\in [1,\infty)$?

Alternatively, we observe the value of the function at $x=0$ and the behaviour as $0>x\to-\infty$ and $0<x\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

You should write $G$ as a composite function of onto functions. Then as an exercise, prove again that a composite function of onto functions is onto.